# Error: Unauthenticated I am using Tenancy for Laravel as Single Domain and Multi-Database with Sanctum API

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

**Problem: {"message":"Unauthenticated."}**

**Explanation:** I am using [Tenancy for Laravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/), having single central domain, but with multi database. Each database has personal_access_token table where I am storing the data. There is a 6 digit code organisation code for each organisation and minimum 8 digit user code for each user. User can only login through the usercode. On the time of login I can easily access the tenant data by having the organisation code and can store the token in the personal_access_token table for that particular database. But after the token generate I can not able to authenticate the user

**Expectation:** Validating the token and get the user info and the set the user's tenant for the future tasks on the particular database.

api.php

```
Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'login']);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/logout', [UserController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('/create-new-user', [UserController::class, 'store']);
});
```

login code

```
public function login(Request $request): mixed
    {
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        try {
            $userCode = (int)(substr($request->username, 3));
            $organisationCode = (int)(substr($request->username, 3, 6));

            $tenant = Tenant::find($organisationCode);
            Tenancy::initialize($tenant);
            
            $user = User::where('users.userCode', $userCode)
                ->join('organisation_infos', 'organisation_infos.code', '=', 'users.organisationCode')
                ->select('users.*', 'organisation_infos.centreName')
                ->first();

            if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
                return APIResponseHelper::ApiResponse(
                    isError: false,
                    responseCode: 4701,
                    responseMessage: "Invalid Username or Password.",
                    responseContent: "Invalid Username or Password."
                );
            }

            if ($user->loggedIn === 1) {
                return APIResponseHelper::ApiResponse(
                    isError: false,
                    responseCode: 4702,
                    responseMessage: "User Already Logged in on another device.",
                    responseContent: "User Already Logged in on another device."
                );
            }

            $user->loggedIn = true;
            $user->save();

            $token = $user->createToken($user->organisationCde . $user->name . $user->mobile . 'Rizwan' . $user->userCode)->plainTextToken;

            Tenancy::end();

            return APIResponseHelper::ApiResponse(
                isError: false,
                responseCode: 4700,
                responseMessage: "Successfully Logged In.",
                responseContent: ["token" => $token, "createdUserInfo" => $user]
            );
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $getTheErrorMessage = $exception->getPrevious();
            return APIResponseHelper::ApiResponse(
                isError: false,
                responseCode: 4713,
                responseMessage: "Error Occurs",
                responseContent: $getTheErrorMessage->errorInfo[2] ?? 'Contact Core Team'
            );
        }
    }
```

logout code php

```
public function logout(): mixed
    {
        $userInfo = auth()->user();
        dd($userInfo->organisationCode);
        $tenant = Tenant::find($userInfo->organisationCode);
        Tenancy::initialize($tenant);
        return APIResponseHelper::ApiResponse(
            isError: false,
            responseCode: 4700,
            responseMessage: "Logout Message",
            responseContent: "Logout Content"
        );
    }
```

[image: I am getting this.]

I have tried to overcome this problem but I failed each time. Now I am expecting a solution from PHP or Developer community.